# What is the location of IntelliJ crash dump files?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, crash-dumps

If `IntelliJ` crashes, where is the location of dump file created?

Nothing in "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3\bin" found by me.

Comment: Do you expect programs writing to the program files directory? Try [Search Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) if you know the file name or extension (`.dmp`?)

Answer (score 0):

The JVM itself creates the dump.
I think it should be in your home directory, which should be C:\Users\yourname on modern Windows versions.